# How to access task by global id (without project) using ActiveCollab API

Tags: activecollab

I can post a comment using the SDK with no problems using the "global" task id (found in the task URL) with the SDK:

```
    $client->post('comments/task/12', ['body' => $commit_msg]);
```

I would like to send put requests to update a task id globally, such as

```
    $client->put('task/12', ['assignee_id' => 4]);
```

Referencing the task by project and then by global id works...

```
    $client->put('project/4/task/12', ['name' => 'new name']);
```

But this should work without having to reference the project.
Referencing the task by project and task # relative to the project (what I  would expect) does not work.

```
    $client->put('project/4/task/2', ['name' => 'new name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, it is not possible to send request to task and skip project, so both arguments are required. Current implementation uses project as sort of a middleware (access permission checks).